# Kotlin in SpringBoot - initialization order for `init`-blocks

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

the following situation is in Kotlin and SpringBoot context.
I would like to know if the initialization of Kotlin's `init` block is executed before or after all dependency injection is executed.

Intuitively `init` is executed when the class is created, so it does not wait for the die DI-framework to be ready. This can lead to potential problems.

Does anyone have more information or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Just taking Spring-Boot as an example:

```kotlin
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping

@Controller
class MyController(private val service: MyService) {

    init {
        println("MyController Init")
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun foo(): String = "bar"
}

@Service
class MyService {

    init {
        println("MyService Init")
    }
}
```

will print the following lines:

```
MyService Init
MyController Init
```

So the dependency will be initialized first. Afterwards the `init` of the class will be called.
The `init` functions will be executed before the constructor of a Kotlin class.